Paradoja con Mongo Atlas
Un problema muy curioso el que me ocurre. Tengo un programa NodeJs que utiliza MongoDB como base de datos, y utiliza Mongo Atlas como alojamiento. La cuestión es que quiero testear en mi PC de manera local, pero soy de Cuba y estoy obligado a usar VPN para acceder. La whitelist de mongo no permite conexiones proxy, las detecta de alguna manera. Así que necesito VPN pero a la vez no puedo usarlo. ¿Alguna idea? Saludos.
Esta pregunta trata mi problema, pero él si pudo solucionarlo, yo no por este pequeño hoyo sin salida. Saludos.

Más allá de los problemas geopolíticos. Cuando hablas de "testear" en local ¿significa que te conectas a una DB local? Entiendo que para acceder a internet (o a Atlas en este caso) necesitas usar una VPN y supongo que así te funciona la conexión. Pero en local no te funciona al no estar en la VPN. Si es así, entonces, usar una DB local me parece que es el camino a seguir, aunque no sé qué tan factible sea eso en tu situación.
